# Route navigation with parameters

Tags: angular, navigation, angular-routing

I am facing a route navigation problem with parameters.
Imagine the following, I'm on a page where the URL is:

```
arenas /: id
ex:
arenas / fjkhe432h4234h23j
```

In this screen I have a button that will change the id of this route, with the intention of changing the page to the desired id. However in the ids exchange, the route is changed but the screen remains static, as if nothing had changed. The route exchange code I am using is as follows:

```
this._router.navigate ([`/ arenas / $ {this.arena._id}`]);
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using navigate where returns the same page, the angle understands that it is just to add a parameter in the URL and not refresh on the screen. So for now, the only solution is to refresh the screen using the method:

> window.location.reload();

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this._router.navigate(['/arenas', this.arena._id]);
```

Comment: I received the following error: Type 'string' has no properties in common with type 'NavigationExtras'.

Comment: Can u show me the entire code block that u have tried

Comment: Of course, I inserted a print in the above question

Comment: Correct the format. It should be `this._router.navigate(['/arenas', this.arena._id]);`

Comment: Unfortunately it still continues with the same problem